# Display numbers with max 3 digits to appear after the decimal point

Tags: javascript

I have a series of numbers. For example:

```
3, 3.4567, 4.5, 5.72, 6.12345
```

How can I show original numbers if they are integers or they have no more than 3 digits after the decimal point and show max 3 digits after the decimal point if there are more than 3? Here is what I want:

```
3, 3.456, 4.5, 5.72, 6.123
```

I used toFixed(), but it makes each number come with 3 digits after the decimal point.

Is there any Javascript method to use to achieve what I want?

--------- update -----------

I used this from the pointer:

Math.round(original*1000)/1000

from the old post. It seems working.

Comment: The answer from the question I linked applies here as well (slightly modified): val = (Math.floor(val * 1000) / 1000).toString()

Comment: See the second answer on the duplicate, answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Number.prototype.toPrecision()` to round to nearest 3 digits after decimal point, then `parseFloat()` the result:

```
var num = 6.12345;
var precise = num.toPrecision(4); //"6.123"
var result = parseFloat(precise); //6.123

var num = 4.5;
var precise = num.toPrecision(4); //"4.500"
var result = parseFloat(precise); //4.5
```

If these numbers are in an array, you can create a function `customPrecision` to map:

```
function customPrecision(num) {
  return parseFloat(num.toPrecision(4));
}

var nums = [3, 3.4567, 4.5, 5.72, 6.12345];
var preciseNums = nums.map(customPrecision); //[3, 3.457, 4.5, 5.72, 6.123]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just cast the fixed strings back into numbers using the unary `+` operator before printing them:

```js
var floats = [3, 3.4567, 4.5, 5.72, 6.12345]

function toMax3Decimals (x) {
  return +x.toFixed(3)
}

console.log(floats.map(toMax3Decimals))
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds. In case the OP didn't know, converting to a Number gets rid of the trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best way, but it works

```
Math.floor(3.4567*1000)/1000
Math.floor(6.12345*1000)/1000
```

Comment: (note this gives output of 3.456 per the example in the question, not 3.457)